# Good practices to write Tags at SVN

Tags: svn

Tags are a vital part at Version Controlling for example SVN.

- When should i write Tags at SVN?
- What information should have a Tags?

Comment: Tag notes? Do you mean tags?

Comment: What are Tag Notes? I have never heard of them, Google has never heard of them, and I cannot find any mention of them in the Subversion documentation.

Comment: @YannisRizos, Sorry, my mistake. I mean tags.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I mean tags. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tags are vital part at Version Controlling for example SVN.

**When should i write Tags at SVN?**

Tags are for releases or stable versions of the code. When you comments out a branch to trunk, then you should write Tags.

**What information should have a Tags?**

As Tags are for releases or stable versions of the code, you can place most release note information at Tag. Following resource related to release note, which may help you to write Tags.

[Good Practices of writing release notes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167578/good-practices-of-writing-release-notes/)

**For naming convention of Tags**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915399/svn-naming-convention-repository-branches-tags

Answer (score 1):

> When should i write Tags at SVN?

When you want to give some revision some any special name, which contain more information, than plain revision number

> What information should have a Tags?

Any, which you want. Mostly, it have to answer question "why it was tagged"